# VLC ActivX plugin not playing video in update IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-9, vlc

I am using vlc ActiveX plugin on web browser IE9 to play video live streaming.

Its work perfect in IE8 but when I update browser from IE8 to IE9 than it not playing video file or live straming.

here is my code.

```
<object type="application/x-vlc-plugin" id="vlc" width="517" height="388" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921">
                    <param name="MRL" id="mrlVideo" value="" />
                    <param name="volume" value="50" />
                    <param name="autoplay" value="True" />
                    <param name="loop" value="false" />
                    <param name="fullscreen" value="false" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                    <param name="toolbar" value="true" />
                    <param name="windowless" value="true" />
                </object>
```

and in javascript I am using these

```
 var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
        var options = new Array(":rtsp-tcp"); 
        var urlVideofile = "hppt://IP:portnumber/"
        var id = vlc.playlist.add(urlVideofile, null, options);
        vlc.playlist.playItem(id);
```

Here is attach image that showing what exactly error is coming

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. You need to access `vlc.playlist` (not `vlc.Playlist`), call `vlc.playlist.add` (not `vlc.Playlist.Add`) and `vlc.playlist.play` (not `vlc.playlist.Play`). IE9’s JavaScript engine is more standards-compliant than previous versions of IE, which [may have allowed case-insensitive access to ActiveX/COM APIs](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29570&seqNum=4).

Additionally, [a bug was introduced](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/8627) in VLC 2.0.6 that breaks the ActiveX API, so you will need to use VLC 2.0.5 or earlier. (Despite what is stated in #8627, this issue is not fixed in VLC 2.0.7, which appears to still include the 2.0.6 ActiveX plugin for some reason.)

Comment: Hi Snover, Thanks for response.
I have review the code for case sensitivity and also try with play() method and add() method but it still have same problem.

Comment: I have added additional information based on research of this issue that is relevant.

Comment: Hi Snover I had try with VLC 2.0.5 but it is not working with live streaming its only play a file on browser. not able to play stream with IE9 while in IE8 its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

We have found the solutions as

```
//var options = [":rtsp-tcp"]; //commented out

//replace the line above with this.Note the CSA key is pre-pended with:
var options = [":ts-csa-ck="+EncryptionkeyValue]; 

//options.push("ts-csa-ck=EncryptionkeyValue");  //commented out as its above now
var itemId = vlc.playlist.add(targetURL, "", options); // continue as normal
var id = vlc.playlist.add(urlVideofile, null, options);
vlc.playlist.playItem(id);
```

Its working fine for Browsers including IE8 which have highest version, IE9, IE10 , 
Chrome, and FF.

Thanks

Comment: I am facing error `Error: vlc.playlist is undefined`. Even using your example exception is `vlc.playlist is undefined`. How do I overcome this ? Any suggestions pls

Comment: problem is coming on all web browser or specific web browser. ?
vlc plugin is installed on your machine ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, VLS is installed and using RTSP, only Firefox and IE supports it, and the exception is in both browsers. Posted question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500712/vlc-webplugin-snapshot-not-working-using-vlc-objects. Also does this work in Win10 Edge Browser ?