# Unable to play video in vlc plugin in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, video-streaming, vlc

I created a sample web site through which i will be able to stream videos across my LAN.

I am using VLC to stream the video or audio.
And on the other side i am using vlc plugin to recieve the currently streamed video.

This all works fine in Firefox and chrome.

But i am encountering issue in IE ,as vlc plugin is not loading in this .
I am using IE8 and my machine is Windows7 64 bit.

Is there any solution to fix this or i have to change vlc to sumthing else which will provide me an option to stream video through command line.

If that is the solution then can anyone tell me the other solutions for it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can see this link , may be it should help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362451/vlc-activx-plugin-not-playing-video-in-update-ie9

Comment: Hi Prashant-thanks for the reply.were u be able to show the vlc in a dialog ,as when i try to show it ,then it shows 3d output window from vlc which i cant even close.

Comment: Yes its working for me. did you facing this type of problem than there is open ticket on videolan site. https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/6518

Comment: yes i am getting teh same issue

Comment: is there any fix for this issue

Answer (score 3):

Try out this...

```
    <object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" width="400" height="300" id="vlc" events="True">
        <param name="Src" value="http://192.168.2.16:8089/webplayer/mediaResources/all/video/test.mpg"></param>
        <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" ></param>
        <param name="AutoLoop" value="no"></param>
        <param name="AutoPlay" value="yes"></param>
        <embed type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" name="vlcfirefox" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="400" height="300" target="http://192.168.2.16:8089/webplayer/mediaResources/all/video/test.mpg"></embed>
    </object>
```